# RVM installing ruby error on arch linux

Tags: ruby, rvm, archlinux

I can install any ruby with rvm, I always get this, on arch linux (manjaro)

```
[anquegi@manjaro-pc ~]$ rvm install 2.1.6 --autolibs=packages
ruby-2.1.6 - #removing src/ruby-2.1.6..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: manjaro/16.06-pre1/x86_64/ruby-2.1.6.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.                                  
Checking requirements for manjaro.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/anquegi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.1.6 - #downloading ruby-2.1.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.1.6 - #extracting ruby-2.1.6 to /home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6....
ruby-2.1.6 - #configuring.....................................................
ruby-2.1.6 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.1.6 - #compiling...............................................................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/anquegi/.rvm/log/1458754652_ruby-2.1.6/make.log
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                     ^
Makefile:280: recipe for target 'ossl_ssl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6/ext/openssl'
exts.mk:192: recipe for target 'ext/openssl/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
linking shared-object socket.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6/ext/socket'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6'
uncommon.mk:180: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

tried without autolibs:

```
[anquegi@manjaro-pc ~]$ rvm install 2.1.6
ruby-2.1.6 - #removing src/ruby-2.1.6..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: manjaro/16.06-pre1/x86_64/ruby-2.1.6.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for manjaro.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/anquegi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.6, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.1.6 - #downloading ruby-2.1.6, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.1.6 - #extracting ruby-2.1.6 to /home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6....
ruby-2.1.6 - #configuring.....................................................
ruby-2.1.6 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.1.6 - #compiling........................................................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/anquegi/.rvm/log/1458753526_ruby-2.1.6/make.log
 #define OSSL_SSL_METHOD_ENTRY(name) { #name, (SSL_METHOD *(*)(void))name##_method }
                                                                     ^
Makefile:280: recipe for target 'ossl_ssl.o' failed
make[2]: *** [ossl_ssl.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6/ext/openssl'
exts.mk:192: recipe for target 'ext/openssl/all' failed
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
installing default callback libraries
linking shared-object dl/callback.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6/ext/dl/callback'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.1.6'
uncommon.mk:180: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

or another ruby version:

```
[anquegi@manjaro-pc ~]$ rvm install 2.2.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: manjaro/16.06-pre1/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.                                  
Checking requirements for manjaro.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/anquegi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.3 - #downloading ruby-2.2.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 12.7M  100 12.7M    0     0   435k      0  0:00:29  0:00:29 --:--:--  422k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
ruby-2.2.3 - #extracting ruby-2.2.3 to /home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3....
ruby-2.2.3 - #configuring.........................................................
ruby-2.2.3 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.3 - #compiling................................................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/anquegi/.rvm/log/1458753949_ruby-2.2.3/make.log
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling stubs.c
linking shared-object strscan.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/ext/strscan'
installing tcltklib libraries
installing default tcltklib libraries
linking shared-object tkutil.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/ext/tk/tkutil'
linking shared-object tcltklib.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/ext/tk'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3'
uncommon.mk:189: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

and with flags

```
anquegi@manjaro-pc ~]$ rvm CFLAGS="-std=iso9899:1999" install 2.2.3 
ruby-2.2.3 - #removing src/ruby-2.2.3..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: manjaro/16.06-pre1/x86_64/ruby-2.2.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.                                  
Checking requirements for manjaro.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/anquegi/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.2.3 - #downloading ruby-2.2.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.2.3 - #extracting ruby-2.2.3 to /home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3....
ruby-2.2.3 - #configuring.........................................................
ruby-2.2.3 - #post-configuration..
ruby-2.2.3 - #compiling..............................................................................
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
showing last 15 lines of /home/anquegi/.rvm/log/1458754170_ruby-2.2.3/make.log
make[1]: *** [ext/openssl/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
installing default socket libraries
compiling init.c
compiling constants.c
checking ../.././parse.y and ../.././ext/ripper/eventids2.c
installing default ripper libraries
linking shared-object ripper.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/ext/ripper'
linking shared-object socket.so
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3/ext/socket'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/anquegi/.rvm/src/ruby-2.2.3'
uncommon.mk:189: recipe for target 'build-ext' failed
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
++ return 2
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

I also tried to reinstall base devel,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems a problem with openssl [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/3548) is a patch

```
curl https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/801e1fe46d83c856844ba18ae4751478c59af0d1.diff > openssl.patch
rvm install --patch ./openssl.patch 2.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks helped me with ruby 2.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04